# Issue in creating helm chart in github repository

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to create a test helm chart in private gitrepo and it is not working.
Here are the Steps:

````
$ helm create helm-test
$ cd <private-gitrepo-dir>
$ cp -r <helm-test-dir> .
$ helm package . # I see the helm-test-<ver>.tgz
$ helm repo index --url https://github.int.privatename.com/<repo-name>
# tgz file and index.yaml are there in the directory
$ git add . && git commit -m "initial commit " && git push
# now pull the chart
$ helm repo add helm-test https://github.int.privatename.com/<repo-name>/
Error: looks like "https://github.int.privatename.com/<repo-name>/ is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 182: mapping values are not allowed in this context```

Can you please help me, where is line 182?
````

Comment: Have you checked in the git repository? There should be a yaml file in helm chart section

Comment: Yes the yaml file is there in the charts directory. I can do a helm package, also an helm index and files are good but for some reason I cannot consume the helm in gitrepo with 'helm repo add...' command